# React Native - How to update my component after ternary function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, components

How can I update my element after return a function? For example:

```
myFunction(condition){
  if(condition){
      return(
         <Text>True</Text>
      )
   }
   return(
      <Text>False</Text>
   )
}

render(){
   return(){
     <View>
       {this.myFunction(condition)}
     </View>
   }
}
```

I have the same case, but the element is updated once Even calling it other times the component is not updated.

Obs.: The condition is changing by other functions.

Thanks!!

Comment: is the `condition` value changing?

Comment: Yes yes. 
I have other functions calling this function and changing the condition.

Comment: is the `condition` stored as part of state.

Comment: No =/ Actually I have no idea how I would store the condition in the state. Because I generated it dynamically too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about make component like

```
changeCondition(condition){
  this.setState({condition})
}

render(){
     return(
         <View>
            <Text>{this.state.condition ? "True" : "False"}</Text>
         </View>
     )
}
```

This is more complying with react rules